# Whenever I enter a value in rate column I want to multiply that value with quantity column and display result in amount column immediately in c#

Tags: c#

I want to enter value in datagridview rate column at run time and then multiply this value with quantity column value and display result in amount column immediately

```
public void calculateGrid()
{
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGVList.Rows)
        {
            double qty = Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells["Quantity"].Value);
            amt = (qty * (Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells["Rate"].Value)));
            row.Cells["Amount"].Value = amt.ToString();
        }
}

public void calAmt()
{
        for (int x = 0; x < dataGVList.Rows.Count; x++)
        {
            tot_amt += Convert.ToDouble(dataGVList.Rows[x].Cells["Amount"].Value);
        }
        txtBoxTotal.Text = tot_amt.ToString();
}
```

When I execute this code I get error

> Input string was not in a correct format.

I called this method in `dataGVList_CellValueChanged()` event.

Comment: Without [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces the problem, it's not possible to say what the problem is. The code you posted isn't even valid as a snippet, as the declaration for `tot_amt` is missing, never mind does it provide any insight as to what might be wrong. You haven't even told us _which_ statement throws the exception, though it seems likely to be the call to `Convert.ToDouble()`. That error tells you that you are trying to parse text that isn't a valid representation of the type you're trying to parse.

Comment: i have declare that variable . for    amt = (qty * (Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells["Rate"].Value))); this line i get error coz i enter value in rate column at run time. Quantity column contain value bt we have to enter value in rate column and then have to perform calculateGrid().

Comment: Please do not use the comments to add information to the question. Edit the question itself to add the new information. And please _do_ provide what was actually asked for, such as (here) **a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example**.